# UITableView selected cell not displaying text when started

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

following code sets cell texts and add a checkMark only to last selected. Always only one cell check marked and works properly excepting when it is displayed for first time. So, text is not showed for that cell (only that one) until you press any other cell. For example, if `cellPos` = 4 when `viewDidLoad`, that cell will not contain text.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    if (indexPath.section == 0) {


        if(indexPath.row == cellPos)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
            cell.selected = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.selected = NO;
        }



        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"English";
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"english.png"];
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Español";
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spanish.png"];
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Deutsch";
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"germany.png"];
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Français";
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"french.png"];
                break;
            case 4:
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Italiano";
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"italian.png"];
                break;
            default:
            break;}
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cellPos = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

Comment: Where are you setting cellPos?

Comment: set at .h and value assigned when viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving the if-else block after the switch block? This way you set the text of the cell before you set the cell to selected. The fact that it only occurs the first time suggests to me that it may be an order of operations problem.

Comment: Yes, I did, but in this case you see a black filled square instead of text. Also only at default selected cell when called first time.

Comment: Try adding `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` to the if block where you instantiate the cell.